# (0.3)^3 == (0.3)*(0.3)*(0.3) returns false in matlab?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I am trying to understand roundoff error for basic arithmetic operations in MATLAB and I came across the following curious example.

```
(0.3)^3 == (0.3)*(0.3)*(0.3)

ans = 0
```

I'd like to know exactly how the left-hand side is computed. [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) suggests that for integer powers an 'exponentiation by squaring' algorithm is used.

"Matrix power. X^p is X to the power p, if p is a scalar. If p is an integer, the power is computed by repeated squaring."

So I assumed `(0.3)^3` and `(0.3)*(0.3)^2` would return the same value. But this is not the case. How do I explain the difference in roundoff error?

Comment: It's interesting to note that WolframAlpha correctly designates this as true.

Comment: Does (0.3)^2 return the same result as 0.3*0.3?  And can you give me the exact result generated by both 0.3^3 and 0.3*0.3*0.3?  It would be quite helpful in reverse-engineering what's going on.

Comment: Please show us where you read that "for integer powers an 'exponentiation by squaring' algorithm is used". I can't find this by a Google search and if it's not the case, then the question is trivial.

Comment: In practice you shouldn't compare floating point values with == (this is true whether you're using matlab or anything else), but rather use something more like [abs(#1 - #2) < epsilon]. If you subtract them (at least on my machine), the difference is -3.4694e-18

Comment: I think the solution would be clear if we could find a way to compile MATLAB to assembly opcodes. Being unfamiliar with MATLAB myself, I don't know whether one is available.

Comment: FWIW, Python 2.7 seems to be giving me the exact same outputs as matlab, which you can disassemble, though I don't know how to do it without constant folding: `dis.dis(compile('.3 * .3 * .3', '', 'eval'),)` gives `0 LOAD_CONST               2 (0.027)`, while disassembling `.3 ** 3` gives `0.026999999999999996`. In both Matlab and Python, we have `.3^2 == .3 * .3` and `.3^4 == .3 * .3 * .3 * .3`, though it's not true for 6 or 8 (breaking both the "even number" and "power of two" theories). For Python, it's at least theoretically possible to track down the exact code used for exponentiation.

Comment: @StephenCanon on my machine (0.3)^2 == (0.3)*(0.3) returns 1, as does (0.3)^4 == (0.3)*(0.3)*(0.3)*(0.3), while the other combinations don't.

Comment: I would say that matrices and number are treated differently by Matlab. And for numbers the answer is the one proposed by @Jeremy

Comment: Could they be implementing it as exp(log(.3)*3)? It would certainly solve the general problem, taking into account signs, but its a terribly inefficient way to do this.

Comment: Interestingly `0.3*0.3*0.3*0.3==0.3^4` does yield `1`. so does `(0.3*0.3)*0.3==(0.3^2)*0.3` and `(0.3*0.3)*0.3==0.3*(0.3^2)`

Comment: @s.bandara I don't know why you were looking in Google. The *document he cited* says "If p is an integer, the power is computed by repeated squaring".

Comment: @EJP Not that it's especially important, but if you look at the edit history the link wasn't added until after s.bandara's comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you sure you don't have those two backwards? I got the opposite of that: `.3 * .3 * .3` is the closest double to .027, `pow(.3, 3)` is the slightly smaller one, in Python, Matlab, and a C program (compiled without optimizations just in case).

Comment: @Dougal: You are right, I had them swapped. `.3*.3*.3` yields 0.0269999999999999996946886682280819513835012912750244140625 and is closer to the exact result. `pow(.3, 3)` yields 0.0269999999999999962252417162744677625596523284912109375. Time to get some sleep.

Comment: @Dougal He cited the document in the original post. The edit just added a link. The Matlab documentation is the Matlab documentation. Not Google.

Comment: Related: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674477/what-number-in-binary-can-only-be-represented-as-an-approximation), and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699596/is-this-a-matlab-bug-do-you-have-the-same-issue/13699708#13699708). Lesson: never use the operator `==` in a floating point context.

Comment: @RudyOldenhuis: The advice not to use `==` with floating point is naïve and is not applicable to this question.

Comment: @alrikai: Comparing floating-point values with a tolerance is not a general solution because it increases false acceptance of unequal values as equal. The proper comparison of floating-point values is application-specific.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: 1) please type my name correctly, 2) did you actually read the questions I linked to? The point is: most operators on floats that are mathematically identical are *almost never* computationally identical, so don't expect `==` to work as you mathematically expect it to. Out there in the wild (so outside your own domain), the most effective bug-preventing way to compare floats it is use a round-off related tolerance (in Matlab, `eps(0.3)`). False positives are so rare in most contexts that it is better to say that the need to handle *them* is application-specific.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Remember that for every single person who needs two quads to be *exactly* identical and thus googled his way to this question, there are at least 1000 people reading it who *don't even really need double* for their application, but use it and run into this issue anyway. As an advice that applies to *most* people, "avoid `==`" definitely does apply.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Your comments are not relevant to this question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's why I didn't post it as an answer, and I started out with "related". But whatever man, go be a happy purist.

Comment: I'm amazed to find so many helpful comments. Thanks to everyone who contributed to the discussion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Dougal I found this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  double x = 0.3;
  printf("%.40f\n", (x*x*x));

  long double y = 0.3;
  printf("%.40f\n", (double)(y*y*y));
}
```

which gives:

```
0.0269999999999999996946886682280819513835
0.0269999999999999962252417162744677625597
```

The case is strange because the computation with more digits gives a worst result. This is due to the fact that anyway the initial number 0.3 is approximated with few digits and hence we start with a relatively "large" error. In this particular case what happens is that the computation with few digits gives another "large" error but with opposite sign... hence compensating the initial one. Instead the computation with more digits gives a second smaller error but the first one remains.

Comment: I got it! What happens is a strange case where the superposition of two larger errors with opposite sign give (by chance) a smaller error then the superposition of the same first error with a smaller second error but with same sign.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about MATLAB, but I tried it in Ruby:

```
irb> 0.3 ** 3
  => 0.026999999999999996
irb> 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3
  => 0.027
```

According to the [Ruby source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L974), the exponentiation operator casts the right-hand operand to a float if the left-hand operand is a float, and then calls the standard C function [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). The `float` variant of the `pow()` function must implement a more complex algorithm for handling non-integer exponents, which would use operations that result in roundoff error. Maybe MATLAB works similarly.

Comment: The numbers look identical to those in Matlab and Python (on my 64-bit OS X machine), and I just tracked down that Python [also calls `pow()`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/floatobject.c#l911). So now we just need to look at the source of `pow()`....

Comment: Okay, with a little digging I found [this implementation of `__ieee754_powf`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openlibm/blob/master/src/e_powf.c#L148) (which is not the one used on any of our systems but might use the same algorithm), and the actual one used in OSX from [this directory](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libm/) (filename `Source/Intel/powf.s`, at least in Libm-315; I don't know which version is used on which OSX). I might look into the actual algorithm later, though it's not especially readable to me....

Comment: @Dougal: That is an old version of OSX Libm, and that file is for the single-precision (float) powf. The double-precision (double) pow is in Intel/xmm_power.c. It has since been written in assembly quite nicely by Stephen Canon. And it will not tell us why Matlab is getting the results it is, since it is not the Matlab implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It seems pretty likely that matlab is calling the system `pow()`, since it gets exactly the same results as python and ruby, or at least is using the same algorithm in this case.

Comment: @Dougal: Showing the same bug would be evidence of a common implementation. Showing the same accurate result is merely evidence of good programming.

Comment: As pointed out above, it doesn't actually get the most accurate number for me; I think you may have mixed up the numbers you got out from your test.

Comment: Having Ruby performs the same as most of the other languages is not surprising. I would have expected Mathlab to do better though...

Comment: For your information, the exact same thing happens in the .NET Framework. I tried this with Microsoft Powershell: `[Math]::Pow(0.3, 3.0).ToString("R")` and `(0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3).ToString("R")`. Same results as above. The absolute difference between the two comes out as `3.4694E-18` (rounded by me). This is `2 ** -58` exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, scalar `^` seems to be implemented using `pow` while matrix `^` is implemented using square-and-multiply.  To wit:

```
octave:13> format hex
octave:14> 0.3^3
ans = 3f9ba5e353f7ced8
octave:15> 0.3*0.3*0.3
ans = 3f9ba5e353f7ced9
octave:20> [0.3 0;0 0.3]^3
ans =

  3f9ba5e353f7ced9  0000000000000000
  0000000000000000  3f9ba5e353f7ced9

octave:21> [0.3 0;0 0.3] * [0.3 0;0 0.3] * [0.3 0;0 0.3]
ans =

  3f9ba5e353f7ced9  0000000000000000
  0000000000000000  3f9ba5e353f7ced9
```

This is confirmed by running octave under gdb and setting a breakpoint in `pow`.

The same is likely true in matlab, but I can't really verify.

Comment: Same results in matlab. It's not super surprising, though, that matrix `^` uses square-and-multiply; `pow` doesn't exactly work on matrix multiplication. Note also that `.^` on matrices is (of course) the same as `^` on scalars.

Comment: It has been changed along matlab history, in on an old matlab 6.5.1, (0.3*([1 1;1 1])).^3 - 0.3^3 is not zero... So the of course should be moderated :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little test program that follows what the system `pow()` from `Source/Intel/xmm_power.c`, in Apple's [`Libm-2026`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libm/Libm-2026.tar.gz), does in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // basically lines 1130-1157 of xmm_power.c, modified a bit to remove
    // irrelevant things

    double x = .3;
    int i = 3;

    //calculate ix = f**i
    long double ix = 1.0, lx = (long double) x;

    //calculate x**i by doing lots of multiplication
    int mask = 1;

    //for each of the bits set in i, multiply ix by x**(2**bit_position)
    while(i != 0)
    {
        if( i & mask )
        {
            ix *= lx;
            i -= mask;
        }
        mask += mask;
        lx *= lx; // In double this might overflow spuriously, but not in long double
    }

    printf("%.40f\n", (double) ix);
}
```

This prints out `0.0269999999999999962252417162744677625597`, which agrees with the results I get for `.3 ^ 3` in Matlab and `.3 ** 3` in Python (and we know [the latter just calls this code](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Objects/floatobject.c#l911)). By contrast, `.3 * .3 * .3` for me gets `0.0269999999999999996946886682280819513835`, which is the same thing that you get if you just ask to print out `0.027` to that many decimal places and so is presumably the closest double.

So there's the algorithm. We could track out exactly what value is set at each step, but it's not too surprising that it would round to a very slightly smaller number given a different algorithm for doing it.

Comment: I don't understand... if you unroll the loop you see that the operation is simply 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3

Answer (score -7):

Read Goldberg's ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (this is a reprint by Oracle). Do understand it. Floating point numbers are **not** the real numbers of calculus. Sorry, no TL;DR version available.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: the paper you suggest does not explain how 0.3**3 could be computed in a different way than 0.3*0.3*0.3

Comment: (0.3)^3 ~~-> pow(0.3, 3.0) != 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3